# Moverio Epson SDK not detect camera permission in android with BT-35E

Tags: java, kotlin, android-camera, android-permissions, epson-moverio

i stay worked on app with the epson BT-35E glasses, im using the epson sample code, but that not works properly.

Im using some differents devices; Huawei P30 and Huawei P20 PRO, but only in some time give me or request me for the camera permissions.

In my manifest i have the permissions associate with the activity.

Some idea about that?

Epson SDK use the compileSdk version 27. Im create an new project with version 27, next an project with version 29, and both dont work.

I get the next catch message.
[Image with catch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R157.jpg)

Thanks!!

Moverio SDK (inside come the SDK and sample code)
https://tech.moverio.epson.com/en/bt-35e/sdk_download.html

Sample code:
https://tech.moverio.epson.com/en/bt-35e/developers_guide/developing_android_apps.html

Comment: It's going to be very hard to get an answer without something you wrote in code.  You need to at least share with us what you are doing to be sure your code is firing the activity & the SDK is getting that activity which would trigger the activity ... as some devices might be compatible but require different functions calling them (sdk should handle but you haven't said if you checked the documentation to be sure sdk and that pair of glasses work).

Comment: Thanks for the sugest, i add a catch image. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you expecting to see the permissions pop up everytime or just the first time used?